# jmeter SocketException Connection reset when performing load test

Tags: jboss7.x, jmeter, java-7

I'm running some http load tests with jmeter to a remote jboss7.1 server where we have a webapp deployed

It is running smoothly until about 200/300 requests are successful then jmeter starst to return the error posted below, I have to say that on the serverside there are no errors in the jboss log.

My environment :

- client:

  ```
  Windows 7
  jmeter 2.5 with 5 threads ramp up 5 sec
  java version "build 1.7.0-b147 64 bit"
  ```
- server:

  ```
  CentOS release 6.3 (Final)
  open jdk "1.7.0_09-icedtea"
  jboss7.1
  ```

I suspect that it is a client problem but not sure how to resolve it, any hints?

The error returned by jmeter is:

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:149)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.SocketInputBuffer.fillBuffer(SocketInputBuffer.java:110)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:264)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultResponseParser.java:98)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:252)
at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:281)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:247)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:219)
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:298)
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:645)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:464)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:262)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:62)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.followRedirects(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1308)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.resultProcessing(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1379)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPAbstractImpl.resultProcessing(HTTPAbstractImpl.java:244)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:334)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:62)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:999)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:985)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:381)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:274)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution just found was to change the parameter in jmeter's Http Request defaults: I had to change HTTP request implementatnion to `Java` instead of `HttpClient4`.

Don't know why this helps but it works.

Comment: It is a known jmeter bug of 2.5, 2.5.1 fixed it and we are now in 2.9, you should trust me and upgrade :)

Comment: I was having the same problem until I switched from HTML4 to Java.  I'm on JMeter 2.9, Windows 7, Java 7 64-bit

Comment: I'm on Jmeter 2.12 and still getting this stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

You are using HttpClient 4 with JMeter 2.5.

It's a knwon issue of this version fixed in 2.5.1.

- https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51863

You are using an old jmeter version, current one is 2.9, I deeply encourage you to follow carefully JMeter versions.

Comment: the response time is not growing to the point where this error happens it is always under 200ms, also the cpu on served is below 10% and no erros on the server are thrown, also the heap usage is ok, wouldn't it be  java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by pear it the server would cut the connections? In my situation it is not reset by pear

Comment: I added a comment to your answer, And updated mine , you should accept mine or change your not to mislead people, thanks

Comment: Thank you for clarification but I have switched to jmeter 2.9 and had the sam issue so your answer seems not to be the correct one, my solution works in both versions si I will treat it as the correct answer, I don't see why this would mislead people...it just works and this is what is important.

Comment: Then open a bug at bugzilla because it is very strange.

Comment: Are you sure that you changed on every sampler the impl to be http4 ? If yes open a bug at bugzilla because it is very strange. We highly use JMeter and did not face this kind issues, and my answer was showing a bug link that is exacly what you faced. If felt your answer was more a workaround that's why I say it s misleading. I tend to always find root cause of issues and not workarounds.